# Extrair dados de um perfil do facebook buscando pelo email

Tags: php

Eu preciso verificar se existe perfil no Facebook, passando como parâmetro o e-mail.

Notei que pela API não tem como.

Mas o site facebook tem a URL:

https://www.facebook.com/search/all/?q=@

No lugar do @ eu coloco um e-mail válido e ele encontra o perfil.

A dúvida seria:

1 - Como posso via file_get_contents acessar essa URL dinamicamente via PHP, e pegar o  nome do perfil e foto.

Note que acessando via navegador, e colocando ali um e-mail válido, ele mostra nome, foto etc do perfil.

Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED); // & ~E_NOTICE
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

define('CHARSET', 'UTF-8');

ini_set('default_charset', CHARSET);
mb_http_output(CHARSET);
mb_internal_encoding(CHARSET);
mb_regex_encoding(CHARSET);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.CHARSET);


/*
A parte que interessa começa aqui. O trecho acima é somente um bootstrap.
*/

$email = 'email@que.deseja.buscar';
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/search/all/?q='.$email;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = html_entity_decode($data);
$data = str_replace(array('<!-- ', ' -->'), '', $data);

class Foo {

    private $data;
    private $dom;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->dom = new DOMDocument();
        $this->dom->validateOnParse = false;
        $this->dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    }

    public function htmlGetContentBySelector($query, $data = null) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        @$this->dom->loadHTML($this->data);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom);
        $xpath_resultset = $xpath->query($query);
        return $this->dom->saveHTML($xpath_resultset->item(0));
    }
}

$c = new Foo($data);

$query = "//code[@id='u_0_d']";
$rs = $c->htmlGetContentBySelector($query);
// O resultado integral
// Exibe o bloco inteiro
//echo $rs; exit;

/*
Agora vamos filtrar e extrair o que interessa

Aqui pegamos a foto.
*/
$query = "//img[@class='_fbBrowseXuiResult__profileImage img']";
$pic = $c->htmlGetContentBySelector($query, $rs);
echo $pic;

/*
retorno
<img class="_fbBrowseXuiResult__profileImage img" src="https://scontent-nrt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c17.0.100.100/p100x100/FOTO-DO-PERFIL" width="100" height="100" alt="NOME DO PERFIL">
*/

/*
O nome e URL do perfil.
*/
$query = "//div[@class='_gll']";
$name = $c->htmlGetContentBySelector($query, $rs);
echo $name;

/*
<div class="_gll"><div><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pagina-da-pessoa"><div class="_5d-4"><div class="_5d-5">NOME DO PERFIL</div></div></a></div></div>
*/

/*
Empresa onde trabalha.
*/
$query = "//div[@class='_glm']";
$job = $c->htmlGetContentBySelector($query, $rs);
echo $job;

/*
     <div class="_glm"><div class="_pac" data-bt="{" ct>å¤åå: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/pagina-da-empresa">NOME DA EMPRESA</a><div class="_1my"></div>
</div></div>
     */
```

Os resultados ainda possuem formatação HTML, no entanto, são bem fáceis de manipular e extrair os dados, caso queira remover o HTML dos mesmos.

A variável `$rs` retorna algo assim:

```
string(1558) "<code id="u_0_d"><!-- <div class="_4-u2 _4-u8"><div id="all_search_results" data-bt="{"session_id":"5505924b49749c699b44850e32fe24fa","typeahead_sid":null,"result_type":"all","referrer":"","path":"\\/search\\/all\\/","experience_type":"simplepps"}"><div class="_1yt"><div class="_3u1 _gli _5und" data-bt="{"id":1251714145,"rank":null,"abtest_version":null,"abtest_params":[null],"section":"main_column","owner_id":null,"sub_id":null,"browse_location":null,"query_data":{"q":"email\\u0040que.deseja.buscar"},"is_headline":false}"><div class="_401d"><div class="clearfix"><a class="_fbBrowseXuiResult__profileImageLink _8o _8s lfloat _ohe" href="https://www.facebook.com/pagina.da.pessoa" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><img class="_fbBrowseXuiResult__profileImage img" src="https://scontent-nrt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c17.0.100.100/p100x100/xxxxxx-FOTO-DA-PESSOa-xxxxx_n.jpg?oh=74ae0b9e2cc130f9800f98d35d64ce36&oe=58AAB17B" width="100" height="100" alt="wa wa" /></a><div class="_42ef"><div class="_glj"><div class="clearfix"><div class="_glk rfloat _ohf"></div><div class="_gll"><div><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pagina.da.pessoa"><div class="_5d-4"><div class="_5d-5">NOME DA PESSOA   </div></div></a></div></div></div><div><div class="_glm"><div class="_pac" data-bt="{"ct":"sub_headers"}">Job: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/página-empresa-onde-trabalha/codigo-qualquer">NOME DA EMPRESA ONDE TRABALHA</a><div class="_1my"></div></div></div><div class="_glo"></div></div><div class="_glp"></div><div class="_3t0c"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div> --></code>"
```

Nota: A URL do facebook, obviamente, não retornará dados de perfils que estejam configurados para ocultar os dados.

Não sei dizer se o resultado pode retornar mais de um perfil. Mas considerando que os e-mails são únicos para cada perfil, então podemos arriscar extrair os dados como nome, url e foto do perfil, sem se preocupar com isso.

Importante também que os valores definidos nos atributos `class` e `id` podem alterar. O script acima pode deixar de funcionar corretamente devido a isso ou também por qualquer outro motivo, futuramente, por ser uma gambiarra e não um jeito oficial e documentado.

Esteja ciente de que requisições anormais podem acarretar em bloqueio do IP que requisita. Portanto, use com moderação.

Comment: Mas isso so vai funcionar se eu me logar? Como vou me logar e rodar esse código...

Comment: Não precisa autenticar. Apenas copie, execute e veja o retorno.

Comment: Ele retorna dizendo que o navegador não é compativel. Como posso setar um user_agent neste exemplo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107759/php-file-get-contents-and-headers